# Trying to migrate in Django 1.9 -- strange SQL error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error"

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-migrations

I don't have a clue what's causing this error.  It appears to be a bug that there isn't a fix for.  Could anyone tell give me a hint as to how I might get around this?  It's frustrating me to no end.  Thanks.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, optilab, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying optilab.0006_auto_20160621_1640...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 121, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 247, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 197, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

Here's the contents of 0006_auto_20160621_1640.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Generated by Django 1.9.6 on 2016-06-21 22:40
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('optilab', '0005_test'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='lasersubstrate',
            name='substrate_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='waveguidesubstrate',
            name='substrate_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='LaserSubstrate',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='WaveguideSubstrate',
        ),
    ]
```

Here's the SQL produced from running 'python manage.py sqlmigrate optilab 0006'

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Remove field substrate_ptr from lasersubstrate
--
ALTER TABLE "optilab_lasersubstrate" RENAME TO "optilab_lasersubstrate__old";
CREATE TABLE "optilab_lasersubstrate" ("substrate_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "optilab_substrate" ("id"));
INSERT INTO "optilab_lasersubstrate" () SELECT  FROM "optilab_lasersubstrate__old";
DROP TABLE "optilab_lasersubstrate__old";
--
-- Remove field substrate_ptr from waveguidesubstrate
--
ALTER TABLE "optilab_waveguidesubstrate" RENAME TO "optilab_waveguidesubstrate__old";
CREATE TABLE "optilab_waveguidesubstrate" ("substrate_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "optilab_substrate" ("id"));
INSERT INTO "optilab_waveguidesubstrate" () SELECT  FROM "optilab_waveguidesubstrate__old";
DROP TABLE "optilab_waveguidesubstrate__old";
--
-- Delete model LaserSubstrate
--
DROP TABLE "optilab_lasersubstrate";
--
-- Delete model WaveguideSubstrate
--
DROP TABLE "optilab_waveguidesubstrate";

COMMIT;
```

Comment: @e4c5  Sorry, don't know what that is nor how to find it.

Comment: It's a simple matter of using `find` command or looking through the tree view in your IDE. However what's needed is the file beginning with 0006 in your migrations folder for optilab

Comment: @e4c5  Thanks for your patience.  I'm editing the post with the file...

Comment: @e4c5  It produced no error.

Comment: @e4c5  I included the sqlmigrate output.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This appears to be the line that's causing the errror:

```
 INSERT INTO "optilab_lasersubstrate" () SELECT  FROM "optilab_lasersubstrate__old";
```

You are usually expected to have a list of columns in those parenthesis. Eg `INSERT INTO "optilab_lasersubstrate" (col1,col2,etc)` however the migration has produced a blank set! Similarly the `SELECT FROM` portion should read as `SELECT col1,col2 FROM`. By some strange set of events you appear to have managed to create a table with no columns!!

I see from your migration file that you are anyway dropping this table. So there isn't any reason to struggle with the `RemoveField` portion. It's code associated with the `RemoveField` that's causing the error. Change your migration as follows:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('optilab', '0005_test'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='LaserSubstrate',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='WaveguideSubstrate',
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: I ran in to this problem also.  This is just a speculation on the cause - I had created and migrated an app that was just a placeholder `class Mumble: pass`.  It had _no_ fields whatsoever.

Comment: Well, this happened to me too, but what I had done was simply trying to delete a lot of models I was no longer using (they were related to Django-CMS plugins)

Comment: BTW, my migrations had the `DeleteModel` commands, but only after some (unnecessary?) `RemoveFields` that seemed to be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Edit base.py in the lines that breaks and update it to:

```
def execute(self, query, params=None):
    if params is None:
        if '()' not in str(query):
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
    query = self.convert_query(query)
    if '()' not in str(query):
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```